# change the default resolution for UI testing with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, resolution

I'm trying to run UI automation with a Jenkins job that runs on a windows VM as a jenkins slave, as a part of a CI pipeline.
I have a problem that the screen resolution is set to be very low (1024, 768)
how can I change the default resolution, so that when jenkins opens a new connection it will be with a larger resolution?

Comment: I am also having the same trouble, though my webdriver window is resolution 1040x784 when fullscreened in Jenkins (1936x1056 when running on my desktop, same machine)

Answer (score 5):

If your UI automation involves running Chrome, you might find it helpful to run [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome). That way, the screen resolution of the slave won't matter as you can specify the resolution you want to be used.

I was able to achieve this with these Chrome startup arguments running on a Windows Server Jenkins slave:

```
--headless --window-size=1920,1080
```

In my case, with Nightwatch, this is a snippet of the nightwatch.json file:

```
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": {
      "args": ["--window-size=1920,1080", "--headless"]
    },
  // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your webapp container started as a local service (tomcat or jenkins slave?). The point is that windows services cannot have GUI and it's even a miracle, that WebDriver somehow manages to open a 1024,768 window :)
Start your webapp container as a console application with a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue while trying to run UI tests on Jenkins

Problem: By default jenkins ran as windows service and have not access to run tests on desktop.

So fix:

1. run >> services.msc >> stop the system service Jenkins.exe
2. right click on Jenkins.exe >> properties >> startup type - Manual >> save
3. create an executable file (.bat, .exe, ...) save it somewhere and type there:

`java -jar "C:\path\to\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8081`

4. add shortcut of this executable file to windows autorun directory

It will run Jenkins on Desktop (non windows service) what allows run your UI tests there

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, running powerscript command as the build step:

```
 set-displayresolution 1920 1080 -Force
```

should do it, but I have some problems with right now...

What has definitely worked: connect to your VM with RDP using desired resolution, then disconnect. The tests will run in the last resolution used.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. And found two different resolutions.

1. If your requirement is to see the chrome browser then open the command prompt and execute the below command

   Java -jar jenkins.war
2. If your goal is just to change the resolution then add the below options and you can see the configure resolution(in the below example resolution is 1920,1080):-

   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("enable-automation");
   options.addArguments("--headless");
   options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
   options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
   options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");